# Optionality of parameters dependent on other parameters

Tags: ruby

I want to define a method with the following signature:

- a. `name` is required.
- b. `all_day` is optional.
- c. `start_time` is required.
- d. `end_time` is required unless `all_day` is `true`.
- e. `location` is optional and is a hash that looks like:

  ```
  location = {name => "Chelsea Piers", address => "10th Avenue", city => "New York"}
  ```

  for which `location[:name]` is required, and other keys are optional.

This is my code:

```
class Event
  def initialize(name, all_day=false, start_time, end_time, **location)
    @name = name
    @all_day = all_day
    @start_time = Time.parse(start_time)
    @end_time = Time.parse(end_time)
    @location = location
  end
end
```

How do I implement requirement d.? If `all_day` is `true` and I don't have `location`, is the syntax in the following code for that parameter:

```
Event.new(name, true, start_time, location)
```

correct? Can I create a new `Event` object like this:

```
Event.new(name, false, start_time, end_time)
```

Comment: Have you considered moving all the optional stuff to named arguments? You'd end up validating the arguments by hand and raising your own `ArgumentError` but everything would be less confusing and easier to read. I find positional arguments get ugly if there are more than a couple of them, doubly so when you start throwing in optional arguments.

Comment: Didn't know about named arguments. Thank you so much for the info!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sidenote:*

```
location = {name => "Chelsea Piers",
            address => "10th Avenue",
            city => "New York"}
```

is not a valid ruby object. It might be either:

```
location = {name: "Chelsea Piers",
            address: "10th Avenue",
            city: "New York"}
```

or:

```
location = {:name => "Chelsea Piers",
            :address => "10th Avenue",
            :city => "New York"}
```

---

*Sidenote #2:*

There is an XY problem: you actually do not need `all_day` parameter at all. It could be derived from whether `end_time` is set or not.

---

And, finally, named parameters and double splat parameter `location` might be mixed. The summing up:

```
class Event
  def initialize(name, start_time, end_time = nil, location_name:, **location)
    @name = name
    @all_day = !end_time.nil?
    @start_time = Time.parse(start_time)
    @end_time = Time.parse(end_time) if end_time
    @location = location.merge(name: location_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: The question said that `location` is optional, but `location[:name]` is required, which does not make sense unconditionally (you can't have the latter without the former). So I interpreted that the OP meant that the latter is obligatory **in case the former is given**.

Comment: @sawa then it could be accomplished with an inner check kinda `location.empty? || location[:name]` only; if that’s true, the OP might simply disregard the `location_name` parameter part of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So OK to use positional arguments over keyword arguments in this case?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!